# Why input type "number" is showing alphabet keyboard for an edit text...?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-edittext

I have a edit text, whose input type is number.

in emulator its working fine i.e, showing the num-pad as soft keypad.

but in the device its showing alphabets keyboard why?

```
<EditText android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
                android:inputType="number" android:maxLength="10"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp" android:textColor="#1b0a00" 
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>
```

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: Can you please post the XML or code that you're using to set the edit text's input type to number?

Comment: Has the device perhaps some other keyboard installed (like swype or so?)

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum code updated..!

Comment: @Mark no the imput method is default android keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give the InputType as number there is a completely new keyboard that gets loaded very different to what you will get by pressing the corner button on your normal keyboard to get numbers . Only certain phones/android versions(i think 2.2+) have this separate keyboard . For the ones that dont have this , The normal keyboard is shown and manual switching has to be done .

Comment: Are you sure about this...? Where can i find more details about this. If you any sources, can you please share with me...?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but worth reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654901/does-android-have-a-numeric-keypad

Answer (score 1):

So from what i've observed setting the inputType to phone should solve the problem . But try a different device to check if ur code works by giving input as number before moving to this option .

Answer (score 1):

I think you must change inputType

FROM :
android:inputType="number"

TO:
android:inputType="phone"

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the device you're testing has some sort of custom keyboard enabled by default that doesn't support a number pad. Try changing the keyboard settings to the standard keyboard on the device and see if it works.

Comment: i am using default android keyboard, it has num pad also, but we need to select after keyboard pop ups..! but i want it when i select the edit text.

Comment: @Noby I'm sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: i am using input method as "android keyboard" in my device. it has a button at corner for number pad, if we click on that button number pad will come. I want that key pad should come when i click on my edit text.

Comment: Just try to press long on the input field and then select input method -> Android keyboard. Is there another option selected? Your code looks good... What device are you using?

Comment: I am using Alcatel OT 890, after changing also no effect.